# Tomcat setup issues

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, tomcat7

I'm trying to run a simple JAX-WS example I found on the web. So I wanted to setup Tomcat 7 under windows xp using Eclipse Helios 32 bit as the web server.

I remembered I had to have my app added as a resource to the Tomcat server, but nothing is coming up as a resource to add. I just have WS-Server and WS-Client projects for the app.

I've done this before, checked the server.xml and see http 1.1 port is 8080, but when I start up Tomcat under eclipse I'm getting a 404 error with this url: http://localhost:8080/, so Tomcat isn't really running properly.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: could be tons of things. You are not giving enough info. For example - what's in the logs?

Comment: See below.  I didn't setup the project correctly as a webapp for tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 - that means the web server is running.  This likely means you don't have anything mapped to the path specified (no servlets/default web page/etc).

Either make a servlet and add it to your web.xml or define a home page html file.

FYI, if you use the "Dynamic Web Project" setup; most of this is done for you.  [Here is a youtube video I always default to when I need to get a review on how to set up a quick tomcat instance in eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs).

Comment: I grabbed the wrong version of Tomcat, I just needed the default zip without the windows services for this; however, I didn't setup the project correctly, even though I've done it before in the past.  Following the video I got it to work. Thanks!